# RubyのExceptionのラッパーでinitializeのsuperの引数に何故Exceptionオブジェクトを渡せるのでしょうか？

Tags: ruby

RubyのExceptionをラッパーしようとして下記を見つけました

https://gist.github.com/rks/2577339#gistcomment-1313963

引用

```
class ClientError < StandardError
  def initialize(e = nil)
    super e
    # Preserve the original exception's data if provided
    if e && e.is_a?(Exception)
      set_backtrace e.backtrace
      message.prepend "#{e.class}: "
    end
  end
end
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Exception.html
を確認したところ

引用：

> new(msg = nil) → exception click to toggle source
>   Construct a new Exception object, optionally passing in a message.

となっており、厳密な型まで記載されてはいないのですが、文字列を期待しているように思います。

ところが上記引用ソースを実際に試したところ問題なく動いたように思います。
`super e`は正しいソースなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

文字列を期待しているわけではなく、`to_s`を実装しているものなら何でも良いから、なのではないでしょうか？

数値の 1 を渡しても、表示されますし。

```
[8] pry(main)> e2 = ArgumentError.new(1)
=> #<ArgumentError: 1>
[9] pry(main)> e2.message
=> "1"
```